# Buffalo NAS Drive on Linux?

Tags: nas

Does anyone know how to use a Buffalo Linkstation NAS in Ubuntu Studio? I'm running the latest stable version, and using the guide at this link. http://forums.buffalotech.com/index.php?topic=7242.0 unfortunately I get the following error message 'mount point does not exist.'

Any help gratefully appreciated.

EDIT As far as I know I've created the mount point. I made the directory that the command line is pointing too.

Comment: Have you created a mount point? Please [edit] your question with information about what you have done so far to mount your NAS. Don't add to the comment chain.

Comment: Please read [ask] and add information which will help us to help you.

Comment: What are you trying to mount, and where? Remember a mount point has to be an empty directory in the file structure.

Comment: I have a number of Buffalo NAS devices used for primarily backup function, they tend to vary on firmware in my opinion, so what works on one model needs tweaking to work on the next model...  However currently I don't know what software you're running (Ubuntu Studio of what release?  GA or HWE kernel?). I found NFS problematic (on some) so opted to use SaMBa on all and with SaMBA the version of Ubuntu mattered with changes needed over various releases.  Provide your release details, your commands used in attempt to mount (be it a terminal command; where I'd start, or your fstab entries).